# How to show field from another table using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem showing fields from another table, where two tables have relationships.

This is my first model:

```
class DataPribadiSiswa(models.Model):
     SiswaID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     WaliKelasID = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
```

My second model:

```
class transaksi_kas(models.Model):
     id_kas = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     siswaID_trans = models.ForeignKey(DataPribadiSiswa, null=True, blank=True)
     kelas = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def transaksi_index(request):
     transaksi = {}
     transaksi['transaksikas'] = transaksi_kas.objects.select_related('siswaID_trans')
     return render(request, 'kastransaksi/transaksi_index.html', transaksi)
```

This is the template:

```html
<table id="simple-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Wali Murid</th>
        <th>Kelas</th>
    </tr>
    {% for kas in transaksikas%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <th>{{ kas.siswaID_trans }}</th>
        <td>{{ kas.WaliKelasID }}</td>
        <td>{{ kas.kelas }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How do I show `{{ kas.WaliKelasID }}` from DataPribadiSiswa?

Comment: Do you mean __{{ kas.siswaID_trans.WaliKelasID }}__

Comment: Exactly, this is what i mean. Thank You @AhmedHosny

Comment: You are welcome @Gusan. I've posted it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to do the following

```
{{ kas.siswaID_trans.WaliKelasID }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transaksi['transaksikas'] = transaksi_kas.objects.select_related('siswaID_trans')` after this you have to make query `get` or `filter` or other.

Example:

```
transaksi['transaksikas'] = transaksi_kas.objects.select_related('siswaID_trans').get(id=id)
```

or

```
transaksi['transaksikas'] = transaksi_kas.objects.select_related('siswaID_trans').filter(your query)
```

this is [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)